# Append only if there are no duplicates

Tags: jquery

I'm making a simple notification list with AJAX and I made it append html with data from a PHP script to a div with `setInterval`. It should only append if it hasn't appended that specific div already, and when I insert a new row in database it should add the **new row only** and not spam the div with old rows.

```
<div class="notification-slider">
    <div class="title">Notifications</div>
    <ul class="notifications-container">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var data = new FormData();
                var user_id = <?php echo $this->session->userdata("id"); ?>;
                data.append("user_id", user_id);

                setInterval(function() {
                    m.request({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: document.location.origin + "/index.php/_notifications/" + user_id,
                        data: data
                    })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        $.each(response, function(index, value){
                            if($(".notification-item").attr("data-noti-attr") != response[index].id)
                            {
                                $(".notifications-container").append('<a href="'+response[index].url+'" class="notification-item" data-noti-attr="'+response[index].id+'"> <li class="uk-clearfix"> <img src="'+response[index].sender_user_id+'" class="notification-image"> <div class="message"> <b>'+response[index].sender_user_id+'</b> '+response[index].content+'<br><br> <div class="uk-text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '+response.time_received+' ago</div> </div> </li> </a>');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }, 1000);
            });
        </script>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm currently using an attribute called `data-noti-attr` for this. Basically if a div with the attribute `data-noti-attr` with the value of `response[index].id` already exist, do not add it again. But it doesn't work like I want it to, as it keep posting duplicates of everything.

How can I accomplish this? *(I tried to explain it as good as I could, ask if it's confusing)*

Comment: I'd strongly advise against using AJAX polling, as it can be very server intensive if you have even a moderate amount of concurrent users - especially when you are polling with very short intervals, as you currently are. I'd suggest you look in to using WebSockets or Server Sent Events. These will both ease the strain on your server, and also solve your problem completely as only new data will be sent to the client, not old data.

Comment: However, as a short term solution, you could simply store the time of the last request and send that in the next request. On your server you can then use that timestamp to only return new records created since that time.

Comment: I looked into WebSockets but didn't quite understand how it worked. I will look into Server Sent Events though! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Attr will return value only for the first item. Read the full docs about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1).

> Description: Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

So you need to filter the found items with your condition (specific data attribute in your case).

For example, using `.is()` method

```
if ($('.item').is('[data-id="' + myId+ '"]')) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just check the length. you can use this

```
if($('.notification-item[data-noti-attr="'+value.id+'"]').length ==0){
....
}
```